# to call c# form in visual c++

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++, c++-cli

I have to create a form in C-sharp(C#) and I want to call it on visual C++. How would I call my forms in visual C++.

Comment: C++ with CLI enabled or native C++?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some solutions.

1) If your willing to turn on the CLR, then you can use Visual C++ .NET code to simply call up the form which is compiled within the C# assembly.

2) If you cant turn on the CLR, and your visual C++ program can use COM to initialize the C# form. Create a COM object within your C# application to host the form. Create a COM factory to implement the LocalServer32 model for DCOM. This is not a simple procedure, so use with caution

3) If your C# form can be converted into a C# usercontrol instead, then you can make your C# usercontrol into an ActiveX and use that instead. It helps if your C++ program can host ActiveX controls. If your using ATL or MFC, you shouldnt have much problem here.